# Using trim on blade - Laravel

Tags: laravel

Good, in php there is a trim function to remove the white spaces, is there a function for blade?

In php it would be like this:

```php
trim($title)
```

I think I understood your question, what I want is to go from this `test text` to `testtext`

Comment: English please ...

Comment: in blade to do what? `trim` just trims the string it doesn't echo it or anything

Comment: that isn't what `trim` is for

Comment: You can replace all spaces with nothing in PHP.

Comment: I have got confused, I must use the replace, thanks @Dharman

Answer (score 0):

You can use @php ... @endphp to call any PHP functions inside blade file. Just to use trim function example is given below.

```
// @php is similar to <?php ?>
@php
$mytitle = trim($title)
@endphp
// Echo my title
{{ $mytitle }}
```